# Conditional to avoid copying text inside a textarea doesn't work

Tags: javascript, textarea, getselection

I am working in a code that add some informations to a copied item in the clipboard. And besides, I'm also working  to avoid that this function don't work when the selected text be inside a textarea, but without success until now.

Take a look at the source. When I run it, the extra informations are added even when the text inside the textarea is selected and copied. **The intention is that extra info don't be added to the copied text inside the clipboard when the selected text be inside a `textarea`.**

Is there anything wrong in my code?

*Important: it doesn't work in Mozilla Firefox.*

```js
function addLink() {

  /* The intention is that extra info don't be added to the copied text when the selected text be inside a textarea */
if (window.getSelection().baseNode.parentNode.tagName === 'TEXTAREA') return; 
  
  var selection = window.getSelection();
    pagelink = "<br/></br/>Full text: " + document.title + "<br/>" + document.location.href;
    copytext = ("“"+selection+"”") + pagelink;
    newdiv = document.createElement('div');
    newdiv.style.position = 'absolute';
    newdiv.style.left = '-99999px';
    document.body.appendChild(newdiv);
    newdiv.innerHTML = copytext;
    selection.selectAllChildren(newdiv);
    window.setTimeout(function (){document.body.removeChild(newdiv);}, 100);
}
    
    document.addEventListener('copy', addLink);
```

```html
<b>It'll be added some extra info to whatever text copied inside this MRE, but the intention is that they don't be added when the selected text be inside a textarea.</b>

<p>When this text is copied, some informations are added to the clipboard.</p>

<p>Here too, but... </p>

<p><textarea id="urlCopied" rows="3" cols="30">how to avoid that extra informations be added when the copied text come from a textarea?</textarea></p>

<textarea placeholder="Paste for testing..." cols="40" rows="7"></textarea>
```

Comment: when I copy right now, I get errors. Please fix your MRE as currently 1) errors are thrown 2) the copying doesn't have anything changed currently

Comment: That's strange @Samathingamajig. I don't see errors in the MRE. ^.~

Comment: `Error: {
  "message": "TypeError: can't access property \"parentNode\", window.getSelection().baseNode is undefined",
  "filename": "https://stacksnippets.net/js",
  "lineno": 23,
  "colno": 12
}` Maybe because I'm in firefox?

Comment: I hadn't realized that, @Samathingamajig. You're correct. In fact, it does not work in Firefox. =\